# CSS code is not displayed in HTML document

Tags: css, html

I have a very basic css question. The code to color my h1 tags is not displayed in the html document (the documents are properly connected) and I simply have no clue what the reason might be. If I add background color in my css file, that is displayed in the html file for instance.Thanks to everyone reading this and (maybe) helping me out

[css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC4gh.png)
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19FZe.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to close `body` tag in css document.

```
body{
    font-family: Gill Sans,Gill Sans MT,Calibri,sans-serif;
}
h1{
    color:red
}
```

moreover you didn't close the `link` tag

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assignment.css">`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have change color of h1 tag
`<h1 style="color:red"></h1>` by inline css 
as u said css is not reflecting on HTML try refreshing the page

Comment: well, css is reflected on the page if I change background color for instance. unfortunately, adding inline css is not an option. do you might have another idea?